# Using a for-each loop within MouseClicked to getX and getY of each object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, chess

I'm a relatively unexperienced programmer who's encountered a problem during the development of a **chess game** in **Java**. I have created a `Handler class` which holds the individual pieces in a `LinkedList`. I now wish to incorporate the function of selecting the individual pieces with my mouse and changing their respective **x- and y-coordinates**, which is required to move them.

In my `MouseClicked()` method I execute a `for-each` loop for every `Piece` object in the `LinkedList`, and check their respective coordinates. The problem occurs here, as the loop executes the following exception occurs:

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException."
```

How do I solve this issue?

Here follows the code in my MouseClicked():

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
    if(clickMode == 0)
    {
        for(Piece pi: handler.piece)
        {
            if(x >= pi.getX() && x <= pi.getX() + 75 && y >= pi.getY() && y <= pi.getY() + 75)
            {
                System.out.println("Piece Selected");
                pi.isSelected = true;
                clickMode = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(Piece pi: handler.piece)
        {
            if(pi.isSelected == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Piece Moved");
                pi.setX(x);
                pi.setY(y);

                pi.isSelected = false;
            }                               
        }
        clickMode = 0;
    }               
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code to see what is null? (Hint check the `handler` if its null or its field `piece`)

Comment: I did just that and solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of your `NullPointerException` is that one of the locations in your `LinkedList` does not contain an instantiated piece. That, or your `handler` instance has not been instantiated. Make sure every object you're using has been constructed.

Comment: I will check it and get back to you.

Comment: I had to use the same handler object as I used to create the pieces.